# Retrieving all the keys from a list of maps

Tags: java, hashmap

I have some data stored in a list of maps

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> myList;
```

Is there an easy way to get all of the keys without going element by element and calling `Map::keySet`?

Say for example I have the list `((Bob, 1), (James, 5))` where Bob and James are both keys in a map, how can I get a list of just `(Bob, James)`?

Comment: You're asking if there's a way to get data from every element in a list without visiting every element in the list? How much easier could it be, really, though?

Comment: I realize it sounds like that, but I didn't know if there was a way to easily flatten the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

- stream the list of maps
- flatten the streams of the keySets
- collect.into a set.

```
Set<String> result =  
  mylist.stream().flatMap(map->map.keySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

And here is another way that avoids flatMapping.  But it does iterate across each map.  MapMulti puts each key on the stream and then they are collected into a set.

```
result = myList.stream().<String>mapMulti((map, consumer)-> {
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        consumer.accept(key);
    }}).collect(Collectors.toSet());

}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, although it still visits all the elements in the list:

```java
final Set<String> keys = myList.stream()
  .map( Map::keySet )
  .reduce( new HashSet<String>(), (a,b) -> {a.addAll( b ); return a;} );
```

It streams the `Map` instances in the list, gets the set with the keys from them, then combines them into a new `HashSet` instance.

If you insist in having an instance of `List` that also contains potential duplicates, try this:

```java
final List<String> keys = myList.stream()
  .map( Map::keySet )
  .reduce( new ArrayList<String>(), (a,b) -> {a.addAll( b ); return a;} );
```

A list without duplicates can be obtained like this:

```java
final List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>( myList.stream()
  .map( Map::keySet )
  .reduce( new HashSet<String>(), (a,b) -> {a.addAll( b ); return a;} ) );
```

---

For *this particular case*, is a pity that `Collection::addAll` returns a `boolean` instead of the collection itself. Otherwise, the code could be simplified to:

```java
final Set<String> keys = myList.stream()
  .map( Map::keySet )
  .reduce( new HashSet<String>(), Collection::addAll ); // THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!
```

Comment: Probably because using `.map().reduce()` is way more complicated than using `.flatMap().toList()`.

Comment: @Chaosfire – ok, then adding a comment should have done the job, too. And `Stream::reduce` may be more complicated (although I would dispute that), but it creates less objects than the solutions using `Stream::flatMap` and should be less expensive though. Although the difference might get visible only for *really* large data sets.

Comment: Well, I am not the downvoter, so this is only a speculation, the reason may be entirely different. While writing reduction logic (accumulator, etc.) is not complicated in itself, it's more complicated compared to `flatMap` followed by a collector, where you use already available functionality.

Comment: @Chaosfire – I assumed that you are not the downvoter, but thanks for commenting anyway. And yes, that `Collection::addAll` returns a `boolean` instead of the collection itself makes the use of `Stream::reduce` a little bit more complex than otherwise necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `stream` with `flatMap`.

example:

```
public List<String> getAllInList(){
List<Map<String,Integer>> list = List.of(Map.of("Bob",1), Map.of("James",2));
    return list.stream().map(Map::keySet).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Replace `Map::entrySet` with `Map::keySet` and it works.

Comment: @tquadrat - my mistake, thank you, I have update it

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

FYI, "going element by element and calling keyset()" can be done in a mere two lines of code:

```java
Set < String > distinctKeys = new HashSet <> ( );
listOfMaps.forEach ( map -> distinctKeys.addAll ( map.keySet ( ) ) );
```

### Looping involved in any solution

> Is there an easy way to get all of the keys without going element by element and calling keyset()?

No. Computers are not magic. If you want to examine various pieces of data in memory, you have to visit their location in memory. For a collection in Java, that visitation means looping through the elements of the collection.

The other Answers using streams using streams are all essentially syntactic sugar for looping through the elements of the collection. Under the covers you are accessing each element of the list, and accessing the set of keys.

### Using `List#forEach` to implicitly loop

Those other Answers with streams are good. But, FYI, I want to show that (a) we can do this without streams, and (b) the code is briefer than you might expect… just two lines. The brevity is due to `List#forEach` in Java 8+.

First, some sample data.

```java
List < Map < String, Integer > > listOfMaps =
        List.of (
                Map.of (
                        "Alice" , 1 ,
                        "Bob" , 2 ,
                        "Carol" , 3
                ) ,
                Map.of (
                        "Davis" , 4 ,
                        "Carol" , 7
                ) ,
                Map.of (
                        "Ernestine" , 5 ,
                        "Frank" , 6
                )
        );
```

Make a new empty set to hold all the keys. A `Set` eliminates duplicate values. So we expect only a single `Carol`, not two.

```java
Set < String > names = new HashSet <> ( );
```

The `List#forEach` automatically loops all the elements of the list. Each element is a `Map` object. We retrieve each map’s keys with a call to `keySet`, and deposit them into our new set.

```java
listOfMaps.forEach ( map -> names.addAll ( map.keySet ( ) ) );
```

When run:

> names = [Bob, Alice, Carol, Ernestine, Frank, Davis]

#### Sequenced collection for alphabetized strings

If we want those strings in alphabetical order, use an ordered set like [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) rather than an unordered set like [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html).

```java
SequencedCollection < String > names = new TreeSet <> ( );
```

When run:

> names = [Alice, Bob, Carol, Davis, Ernestine, Frank]

[`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) is [new in Java 21](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431). In earlier Java, use [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html). In ancient Java, use [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html).